# Routing to REST API on ElasticBeanstalk through CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

We have this setup where

- Express API running on Elastic Beanstalk environment behind an ALB.
- S3 bucket for static content.
- CloudFront as an access point for everything.

For some reason, CloudFront simply refuses to return a response from the API.

PathPatterns are configured like this:

[image: Screenshot]

where APIOrigin is pointing to the the ALB in front of the Beanstalk environment.

The only thing the I'm getting from the endpoint xxxx.cloudfront.net/api/health is this:
[Sorry, cannot embed images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPyr5.png)

Yet calling the addess {loadbalancerUrl}/health returns the correct response.

The xxx.cloudfront/api response contains headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Access-Control-Allow-Methods
```

exactly like the Express API on Beanstalk sets them, so some communication exists there, but no response. (JSON response is expected)

We are avoiding using API Gateway for company reasons.

What can I try next?

Comment: Try changing the path pattern to `/api/*`.